# Selenium combination keys (Ctrl+99)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

I have to use combination keys (Ctrl+00) in Selenium (Java) to submit a form, which will not accept key presses from the numpad, but only the keys from the backspace row. Could anybody please help?

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.Control, Keys.NUMPAD9, Keys.NUMPAD9);

driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.Control, Keys.NUMPAD0, Keys.NUMPAD0);
```

Comment: To send `Ctrl+00` why would you `sendKeys(Keys.9, Keys.NUMPAD9, Keys.NUMPAD9, Keys.NUMPAD9)`?

Comment: I need them both for the script, Thanks DebanjanB.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Keys class:

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "0"), Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "0"));
```